# Entry element query missing user field data when user is suspended

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, entries

I have a channel in which each channel entry has a "users" field type that is limited to one user. My code below works fine when the user is not suspended, however if I suspend the user, the then `$entry->user` field is null rather than set to the array of one user like its normally set to.

Here is my code:

```
        // do criteria code to get pending transfers from patients channel
    $account = $userIdentity->getFieldValue('account')->first();
    $entryQuery = Entry::find()
        ->section('networkAssets')
        ->relatedTo(['targetElement' => $account, "field" => "account"])
        ->orderBy('title asc');


    // Execute the query and get the results
    $entries = $entryQuery->anyStatus()->all();
    $assets = [];
    foreach($entries as $entry) {
        $user = $entry->user->one();
        $assets[] = [
            'id' => $entry->id,
            'slug' => $entry->slug,
            'title' => $entry->title,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'first_name' => $user->firstName,
            'last_name' => $user->lastName,
            'address1' => $entry->address1,
            'address2' => $entry->address2,
            'state_province' => $entry->stateProvince,
            'city' => $entry->city,
            'postal_code' => $entry->postalCode,
            'country' => $entry->country,
            'username' => $user->username,
            'password' => '',
            'status' => $user->getStatus(),
            'date_created' => $entry->dateCreated->format('m/d/Y') . "<br>" . $entry->dateCreated->format('H:i:s T'),
            'last_login' => $user->lastLoginDate ? $user->lastLoginDate->format('m/d/Y') . "<br>" . $user->lastLoginDate->format('H:i:s T') : 'Never',
            'phone' => $entry->phoneNumber
        ];
    }

    return $assets;
```

You can see in the `foreach` loop that Im getting the user from the looped entry result and storing it in a `$user` variable.

When I try to use `$user` I get a notice because $user is null.

**How can I force this code to return the linked user in the user field even  when the user is suspended?**

Comment: The `->anyStatus()->` was me just trying things to get this to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User queries by default will only return active users, not pending or suspended ones.

To include suspended users, change this line:

```php
$user = $entry->user->one();
```

to this:

```php
$user = $entry->user->status(['active', 'suspended'])->one();
```

Or if you want to include pending users as well (users who haven’t activated their account yet), you can do this:

```php
$user = $entry->user->anyStatus()->one();
```

Comment: This did the trick! thanks! (spelling is hard)